# Python - tkinter button freeze

Tags: python, tkinter

I have problem with freezing application in Python. I used tkinter library to make some app. When I using Send button it calls the functions that lasts 3 minutes and freezing application on this 3 minutes... I want to see all logs from this function "live". I can't wait 3 minutes and then get all the logs.

Below is example of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import time


class Frames:

    def main_frame(self, win):

        # Main Frame
        main = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text="")
        main.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="WENS", padx=10, pady=10)
        return main

    def button_frame(self, win):

        # Button Frame
        butt_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text="Button")
        butt_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NWS')

        def _send_button():
            for i in range(10):
                self.write_text_console("{0}\n".format(i))
                time.sleep(0.5)

        # Send Button
        ttk.Label(butt_frame, text="                                         ").grid(column=0, row=8)
        button = tk.Button(butt_frame, text="Send", command=_send_button, foreground='black')
        button.grid(column=0, row=13, sticky=tk.EW)

    def scrolled_text_widget(self, win):
        ttk.Label(win, text="                                         ").grid(column=0, row=1)
        ttk.Label(win, text="Console Output:").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        self.scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win, width=100, height=10, wrap=tk.WORD, state="disabled")
        self.scr.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=5)

    def write_text_console(self, string, color="black", tag="console"):
        self.scr.configure(state='normal')
        self.scr.insert('end', string, tag)
        self.scr.tag_config(tag, foreground=color)
        self.scr.configure(state='disabled')
        self.scr.see("end")


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("845x300")
win.resizable(0, 0)
frames = Frames()
main = frames.main_frame(win)
frames.button_frame(main)
frames.scrolled_text_widget(main)
win.mainloop()
```

This example showing my problem. When you click the Send button it freeze app for 5s. But I need to see the logs during the loop.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Re write your code such that it works with `win.after()`. And why not use `__init__` and define attributes like `win` inside that, so it can be used anywhere, rather than passing it over each method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tkinter is running a loop in your main thread, that's why your app freezes when you click on a button. The solution is to create a new thread.

1- You have to import threading

```
import threading
```

2- Start a new thread in your _send_button() function. It should be like this.

```
 def _send_button():

        def click_button():
            for i in range(10):
                self.write_text_console("{0}\n".format(i))
                time.sleep(0.5)

        threading.Thread(target=click_button).start()
```

[Learn More About Threading In Python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Comment: While this would work with small codes, `tkinter` is single threaded, and it cannot communicate between two threads.

Comment: I was thinking about threading but I don't used it before. Thank you for your answer and link where I can learn about it more!

Answer (score 0):

To freeze the button, add `state= DISABLED` in the specific button widget.

```
from tkinter import *

#Create an instance of tkiner frame
root= Tk()

#Define the geometry of the function
root.geometry("400x250")

Button(root, text="OK", state= DISABLED).pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```